# Data does not get reflected in real time in Qt TexttEdit widget

Tags: c++, user-interface

I am trying to scan files and its sub directory , the code from Qt Examples works absolutely fine and displays data with QDebug() .
However when i try to  it.next() data to a Qlable or textEdit widget , it doesn't show the data in realtime. The data is reflected after the it.hasNext() gets completed. I want to show real time scanning status in the textedit box - Self is new to Qt.

How to show the status for the file being scanned in real time,  in the Qt textEdit widget  ?

Code is given below .

```
void  MainWindow::findFilesRecursively(QDir rootDir) {
    QDirIterator it(rootDir, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        qDebug() << it.next();
       //  ui->textEdit->append(it.next());    <<<<<<---- This is note getting updated realtime,
                                                          Data get populated after the scan in complted.
                                                                  
    }
}
```

### Error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0JTq.png)

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be your problem, but do you understand what your code is trying to do?

Your debug statement calls it->next(). You then in your commented-out code call it->next() a second time. If your directory only contains a single file, you've already dumped it. The debug statement eats it.

What you need instead:

```
 QString fName = it->next();
 qDebug() << fName;
 ui->textEdit->append(fName);
```

I'm not absolutely positive this is your problem, because I don't know if you commented out your qDebug when you ran it or how big your directory is. There might be something else going on.

Comment: Note also that if the code involved doesn't return to the event loop, the UI won't update. Qt requires you to let the event loop run and the UI will pause during your code. If you have to do something that takes a long time, then you need to create a worker thread.

Comment: Hi Joseph , Greetings .

Comment: Hi Joseph , Greetings .
My root directory which I am scanning has around 50 Sub directory, with 100+ files . Its a big tree.
I tried your solution , it worked from small Dir tree, not for big. 
I think it a problem of threading or something .

Comment: Is your code in a thread? I don't believe that will work. I think the UI has to be modified from the main thread.